# How do you select an input tag and use it in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use the input tag using a line, and I'm trying to select the id of the input tag and use it in the parameters of an if statement but I can't seem to do that. The selection doesn't need to be by the id.

This is the input tag:

```html
<label for="budget">Cake Budget</label>
<input id="budget" type="number" >
<br><br>
```

Comment: you want to get the input value ?

Comment: I want to select the input tag and use it in the parameters of an if statement

Comment: this is not a HTML element but a string you need to **PARSE** and find inside 'id="budget"` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the input tag as a variable:

```
var tag = document.getElementById("budget");
```

from where you can receive the text in the tag if desired (`tag.value`).

Answer (score 0):

html:

```html
<input id="budget" type="number" onchange="update()">
```

JS:

```js
function update(){
    var e = $('#budget').value
    if(e > 100){
        /*Your Code Here*/
        // 'e' is the name of the variable that has the 'budget' value in it.
    }
}
```